# Running SQL query on specific server name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, dynamic-sql

I am currently running the below query in SSMS which runs the query that have databases ending with `AccountsLive`....is there anyway to also incorporate server names as well?

For instance, I want the below to run on only server names ending with `ACCDB1`. Is this at all possible?

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql = STUFF(
(SELECT NCHAR (10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) + N'SELECT
LEFT('+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N', LEN('+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N') - 12) AS Office,
pt_copysupp COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as S_Code
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.dbo.pl_transactions'
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE NAME like '%AccountsLive'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '');
exec(@Sql);
```

Comment: Are you referring to Linked Servers, specifically Linked Servers already configured on the instance you're connected to?  https://jwcooney.com/2011/10/26/sql-server-how-to-list-the-full-properties-of-all-linked-servers/

Comment: @MatBailie after checking, they are linked servers already configured on the instance....how would the above code run on all of these linked servers?

Comment: `sp_linkedservers` returns the list of linked servers.

Comment: @peterk One server at a time, in a loop, using the structure shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query `sys.servers` to get the list of linked server with name ending with `ACCDB1`

```
select name
from   sys.servers
where  name like '%ACCDB1'
```

For each linked server `@server`, use [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to execute your query `@Sql` on that server. You will need to use dynamic query to form the `OPENQUERY` and execute it

```
declare @dsql nvarchar(max)

select @dsql = 'select * from OPENQUERY(' + QUOTENAME(@server) + ', ''' + @Sql + ''')'

print @dsql

exec sp_executesql @dsql
```

Comment: perfect - thanks @Squirrel have managed to get this solved using this as a starter!